# No 'return' in Golang for method that return values

Tags: go

I'm looking to the video tutorial of Go. I see there a type declaration and method that have to return a pointer of that type.

```
type testType struct {
    value int
}

func (h *testType) testFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // we have empty body
}
```

As you see, function body is empty, there is no return statement.

- Why does it compile? I did not know that missing 'return' directives are permitted for methods that have to return some value. Could you tell me when they are not mandatory?
- What value will be returned in this case? Always nil?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is not the return type of the function, it's a method and that is called the receiver type.

See [Spec: Function declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations) and [Spec: Method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations).

The return type is at the end of the function [Signature](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Signature), for example:

```
func testFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *testType {
    return nil
}
```

This is a function, having a return type of `*testType`.

This:

```
func (h *testType) testFunction(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // we have empty body
}
```

Is a method with receiver type `*testType`, and no return types.